# Unable to find package 'angularjs'

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am unable to install Angularjs through Nuget Command. I am using Vs 2015 .

```
PM> Install-Package angularjs
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'angularjs'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package angularjs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.1923506
```

Answer (score 0):

See below link is proof that you are executing correct command - https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/

Just one thing I need to ensure Check you have choosen All in Package Source while running command in Package Manager Console may be your forget choose that. See the image below -

[image: Package Console]